# How to change list number in Django templates loop?

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

So basically I have a list of 10 items from my database that I'm looping into one of my templates. How could I dynamically change the number of the list item as well? Here is what my loop looks like

```
            {% for list in lists %}
                <div class='collection-item avatar cart-row'>
                    <div>
                        <h5 class="center container left card-title">{{ list.value }}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

The current result is
"Shirt", "Shoes", "Pants", etc. What I want to achieve is "1. Shirt", "2. Shoes", "3. Pants", etc.
My question is how could I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`forloop.counter`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) this is a counter that starts at one:

```
{% for list in lists %}
    <div class='collection-item avatar cart-row'>
        <div>
            <h5 class="center container left card-title">{{ forloop.counter }}. {{ list.value }}</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

You might however want to [use css to do this instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).